# React - Object field as dependency of useMemo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, eslint

I have the following code:

```
   const iconMap = useMemo(() => ({
     HomeStacks: {
       iconName: "home",
       iconType: "material-community",
     },
     ActivityStacks: {
       iconName: "bell",
       iconType: "material-community",
       badgeCount: badges["activity"],
     },
   }), [badges["activity"]]);
```

And, for some reason, ESLint is throwing me an error from the rule "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps":

> React Hook useMemo has a missing dependency: 'badges'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps

So, is it not valid to use object fields as dependencies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It definitely is, but `eslint` appears to be confused by the bracket notation accessor. In newer versions of `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` it is perfectly fine to use dot notation in the dependency list, but for any use cases where it will complain, you can always extract the property to a constant above the dependency list like so (assuming you do not want to suppress the warning):

```
 const activity = badges["activity"];
 const iconMap = useMemo(() => ({
     HomeStacks: {
       iconName: "home",
       iconType: "material-community",
     },
     ActivityStacks: {
       iconName: "bell",
       iconType: "material-community",
       badgeCount: activity,
     },
   }), [activity]);
```